# How to Assign a Static Internal IP Address in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, home-networking

I want to open a port for my PC, so I assigned a static IP for it. When I try ipconfig cmd line I get the IP address I assigned, but when I check DHCP clients list in my router, I find a different dynamic IP. My router is  [TL-WR340G](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WR340G#over).I'm a complete noob, so I'm not sure if the way I used is correct, how can I fix that?

Comment: Have your router always assign the same ip, thus it the ip will become static, follow the directions for your router model.

Comment: If you switched the machine to static IP successfully, the entry in your router might just be it's memory of the machine (or does it state whether it is online or not?). Ramhounds suggestion is still good though, because that way you can manage everything in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to setup a Static DHCP address.  It looks like from reading through the manual the TL-WR340G calls this "Address Reservation."

From section 3.6.3 - Address Reservation of the [TL-WR340G Manual](http://www.tp-link.com/resources/software/200943083466.pdf):

> To Reserve IP addresses:
>
> 1. Click the Add New button. (Pop-up Figure 3-26)
> 2. Enter the MAC address (The format for the MAC Address is XX-XX-XX-XX-XX-XX.) and IP  address in dotted-decimal notation of the
>      computer you wish to add.
> 3. Click the Save button when finished.

You can find your MAC address in the Client List.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run `ipconfig /all` in cmd and write down the `MAC address` of your ethernet card (one with address given by you).
2. Log on to your router and goto `DHCP -> Address Reservation`
3. Click `add` and fill in your `MAC address` and IP that you set to your computer, set `enabled` and click `Apply`

That's it. Now, you can set on your PC to get address from DHCP and you'll get one you filled in.